# Calabash-Android run file not found

Tags: android, windows, calabash

I am trying to run calabash-android on Windows 8. I have installed Ruby 2.0.0 and I have added the following paths (System variables) :

```
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk
ANT_HOME = C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.0-src\apache-ant-1.9.0\apache-ant-1.9.0-bin\apache-ant-1.9.0
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
Path = C:\Ruby200-x64\bin; C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.0-src\apache-ant-1.9.0\apache-ant-1.9.0-bin\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin
```

Why is it not working when I type calabash-android run NetPocoCache.apk in the command line? I get the following error:

> C:\Users\Anna\workspace\NetPocoCache\bin>calabash-android run
>   NetPocoCache.apk -v No test server found for this combination of app
>   and calabash version. Recreating test server. 2013-05-13 12:01:12 -
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21/bin/keytool.exe" -v -list -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore "C:/Users/Anna/.android/debug.keys tore"
>   -storepass android 2013-05-13 12:01:12 - Aliasnamn: androiddebugkey Skapat den: 2013-maj-13 Posttyp: PrivateKeyEntry Lõngd pÕ
>   certifikatskedja: 1 Certifikat[1]: ─gare: CN=Android Debug, O=Android,
>   C=US Utfõrdare: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US Serienummer:
>   2d0236c8 Giltigt frÕn den: Mon May 13 10:33:24 CEST 2013 till: Wed May
>   06 10:33:24 CEST 2043 Certifikatets fingeravtryck:
>            MD5: 02:35:0D:D6:DA:3A:7D:B1:C7:29:43:B2:77:91:6F:48
>            SHA1: C2:45:61:B9:66:58:D6:4A:9D:F8:A4:AF:14:9B:EA:F5:23:81:47:E8
>            SHA256: 9F:82:C4:B1:B3:44:4A:7E:F3:44:8B:AD:7A:E5:07:30:F6:72:C5:EA:8E:C8:34:D9:F5:29:F5:F3:4C:92:0E:03
>            Namn pÕ signaturalgoritm: SHA256withRSA
>            Version: 3
>
> Tillõgg:
>
> ## 1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false SubjectKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 3F 74 AD 07 92 A3 17 06   9E C0 AF 19 DC E4 E1
>
> 3D  ?t.............= 0010: 24 AA 97 24
>   $..$ ] ]
>
> 2013-05-13 12:01:12 - MD5 fingerprint for keystore
>   ("C:/Users/Anna/.android/debug.keystore"):
>   02:35:0D:D6:DA:3A:7D:B1:C7:29:43:B2:77:91:6F:48 2013-05-13 12:01:12 -
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21/bin/keytool.exe" -v -printcert
>   -file C:/Users/Anna/AppData/Local/Temp/d20130513-2828-sej8xs/M ETA-INF/CERT.RSA 2013-05-13 12:01:12 - ─gare: CN=Android Debug,
>   O=Android, C=US Utfõrdare: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
>   Serienummer: 2d0236c8 Giltigt frÕn den: Mon May 13 10:33:24 CEST 2013
>   till: Wed May 06 10:33:24 CEST 2043 Certifikatets fingeravtryck:
>            MD5: 02:35:0D:D6:DA:3A:7D:B1:C7:29:43:B2:77:91:6F:48
>            SHA1: C2:45:61:B9:66:58:D6:4A:9D:F8:A4:AF:14:9B:EA:F5:23:81:47:E8
>            SHA256: 9F:82:C4:B1:B3:44:4A:7E:F3:44:8B:AD:7A:E5:07:30:F6:72:C5:EA:8E:C8:34:D9:F5:29:F5:F3:4C:92:0E:03
>            Namn pÕ signaturalgoritm: SHA256withRSA
>            Version: 3
>
> Tillõgg:
>
> ## 1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false SubjectKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 3F 74 AD 07 92 A3 17 06   9E C0 AF 19 DC E4 E1
>
> 3D  ?t.............= 0010: 24 AA 97 24
>   $..$ ] ]
>
> 2013-05-13 12:01:12 - MD5 fingerprint for signing cert
>   (C:/Users/Anna/workspace/NetPocoCache/bin/NetPocoCache.apk):
>   02:35:0D:D6:DA:3A:7D:B1:C7:29:43:B 2:77:91:6F:48
>   C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:29:in
>   `` `': No such file or directory - java -jar "C:/Ru
>   by200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/lib/calabash-android/lib/manifest_extractor.jar"
>   "C:/Users/Anna/workspace/NetPocoCache/bin/N etPocoCache.apk"
>   (Errno::ENOENT)
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:29:in ``
>   manifest'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:12:in
>   `package_name'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:21:in`
>   block (2 levels) in calabash_build'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:17:in
>   `chdir'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:17:in`
>   block in calabash_build'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:88:in `mktmpdir'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:16:in`
>   calabash_build'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:49:in
>   `build_test_server_if_needed'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/bin/calabash-android-run.rb:16:in`
>   calabash_run'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.4.4/bin/calabash-android:76:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/calabash-android:23:in`load'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/calabash-android:23:in `'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have all the necessary executables in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
You can test that Java is found by executing `java -version` from CMD.

You also need to add the JRE to your **Path** so that the programs javaw etc. are found.
You can test that Javaw is found by executing `javaw` from CMD.

I have not gotten calabash to work on Ruby 2.0 however 1.8.7 works for me.
(Ruby 2.0 gives me a gherkin error)
Again you can test that Ruby is found by executing `ruby -version` from CMD.

Other than this, your paths seems correct

Answer (score 0):

On a mac machine, the following steps should resolve it (I have had a similar problem):

1. Check that keystore file is available in framework.
2. Check ruby version using **ruby -v**
3. Check that all gems are available ex. **calabash-android, calabash-cucumber**
4. If your default ruby version gets changed 
   use below command
   for my case I'm using **rvm --default use 2.1.2**